# Reusing UITableViewCell moves subview frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm subclassing UITableViewCell. In the xib for my custom cell, I have an UIImageView that has a frame of (0, 0, 57, 57). It has autolayout constraints set to top, left, width, and height.

When the table view is first rendered, all the cells look fine. But when I scroll around, (and thus reusing the celles) the frame for the UIImageView shifts to (15, 0, 57, 57). None of the other subviews seem to be affected.

[image]

The UITableViewDataSource:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Content* content = [[[ContentManager sharedContentManager] allContent] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ContnetCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell loadWithContent:content];
    return cell;
}
```

The Cell:

```
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.imageView.image = nil;
}

-(void)loadWithContent:(Content*)content
{
    self.imageView.image = content.contentImage;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a custom cell right?  If you use the same property names for your custom images or labels  as those found in a default cell (i.e, `imageView`, `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel`), strange things can happen. Try renaming `imageView` to something else and see if that fixes it.